# Pass some array parameters into wasm

Tags: javascript, c++, memory, webassembly, emscripten

I want to call the init function  of wasm , whose C code is as follows，so I need pass arrays from javascript to wasm.

```
int  EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE init(int* playRecipes1, int* playChefs1, int* recipe2Change1,int* scoreCacheNoEquipIndex1, int* scoreAddCacheNoEquip1,short* disordePermuation1) {
playRecipes = playRecipes1;
playChefs = playChefs1;

recipe2ChangeLength = recipe2Change1[0];
scoreAddCacheNoEquipLength = scoreAddCacheNoEquip1[1];
scoreCacheNoEquipIndexLength = scoreCacheNoEquipIndex1[1];


recipe2Change = (int*)(recipe2Change1+1);
scoreCacheNoEquipIndex = (int * )(scoreCacheNoEquipIndex1 + 2);
scoreAddCacheNoEquip = (int *)(scoreAddCacheNoEquip1 + 2);
disordePermuation = (short *)(disordePermuation1+2);

return recipe2ChangeLength;
```

}

I learned that to pass array, I can use the Module._malloc() to create array.But the return value of _ malloc is very large，
So, when I use Module.HEAPU8.set (data, dataPointer), I encounter the error: Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: offset is out of bounds.
At Int32Array.set (< anonymous >)

Every time I run the program, the first time I call Module._malloc (), the return value is always 5245672.

such as :

```
function arrayToIntMemorySegment( arrays) {
let length1 = arrays.length;
let length2 = arrays[0].length;
let size = (length1 * length2 + 2);

let ptr = Module._malloc(size * 4);
let segment = new Int32Array(size);
let index = 0;

segment[index++]=length1;
segment[index++]=length2;

for (let i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
    for (let i2 = 0; i2 < length2; i2++) {
        segment[index++]=arrays[i][i2];
    }
}

Module.HEAP32.set(segment, ptr);
return ptr;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HEAP32` is a 32-bit view of your memory, but `malloc` returns a byte offset, so you need pass `ptr >> 2` as the second argument to `Module.HEAP32.set`.

If you were instead using HEAP8 or HEAPU8 than you could use `ptr` directly.

Comment: The value returned from malloc (5245672) looks about right since emscripten reserves 5Mb for the stack by default.

Comment: thank,you are right.Could you help me again, please？If I want to understand why need  （ptr >> 2), I should learn from where?